# Cypher - Distinct results before ordering them

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am kind of new to Cypher, sorry if I missed the logical solution. Thank you for your help :)

The graph I work with makes a network of research publications with their publication date and creates a relation to the molecules mentioned in the publications.
I tried to get an overview of the number of new molecules added per year.

I tried:

```
MATCH (p:Publication)-->(m:Molecule)
RETURN DISTINCT datetime(p.releasedDate).year AS release, count(m) ORDER BY release
```

This returns a list with the number of distinct molecules per year, but it still is possible (and likely) that molecules in the first year are also in the second year, since the order by seems to be applied before the distinct.

Is there a way to first make a list is all the distinct molecules, and then order them by year?

Thanks again for any help. If more information is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to write a few queries to illustrate some options:

```
// Number of molecule mentions per publication year
MATCH (p:Publication)-->(:Molecule)
WITH datetime(p.releasedDate).year AS release, count(*)


// Number of unique molecules mentioned per publication year
MATCH (p:Publication)-->(m:Molecule)
WITH datetime(p.releasedDate).year AS release, count(distinct m)


// Refactor so we know the year a molecule first mentioned
MATCH (p:Publication)-->(m:Molecule)
WITH m, min(datetime(p.releasedDate).year) as yearIntroduced


// Number of new molecules this year, and how many times where they mentioned
MATCH (p:Publication)-->(m:Molecule{yearIntroduced:2021})
RETURN m.name, count(*) as numberOfTimesMentioned


// Same but without refactoring
MATCH (p:Publication)-->(m:Molecule)
WITH m, min(datetime(p.releasedDate).year) as yearIntroduced
WHERE yearIntroduced=2021
MATCH (p:Publication)-->(m)
RETURN m.name, count(*) as numberOfTimesMentioned
```

I hope that helps!

Aggregating Functions in the Cypher manual: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a try and it definitely helped me :)